# Common label for a groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

This can be considered a combination of the following questions

[How can a title be placed for a group of pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51002/how-can-a-title-be-placed-for-a-group-of-pgfplots)

[Align ylabels of grouped plots at a common line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75444/align-ylabels-of-grouped-plots-at-a-common-line)

The following piece of code renders two plots, one above the other, and attaches
a common ylabel to both.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
%% Just some font that has serifs for maths                                          
%% Yes; this particular combination is horrible                                      
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel = ylabel, y unit = m/s]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1000) (2,0)};
  \end{groupplot}

  \node at ($(group c1r1.west)!0.5!(group c1r2.west)$)
  [xshift=-1.5cm] % Problem #1: estimated distance                                   
  {\rotatebox{90}{ylabel [$\mathrm{m/s}$]}};
  % Problem #2: Copying pgfplots internals,                                          
  % i.e. /pgfplots/unit code/.code 2 args={\mathrm{#1#2}}                            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering]

There are two problems: It would be nice if the `near ticks` mechanics worked for this case, too, i.e. the optimal distance from both plots were determined automatically; on top of that, if units are used, the ylabel isn't just a bit
of text anymore, but something more complicated; and I'd rather not reinvent
that machinery.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You might find the following approach helpful.  Here I just add the label to the second plot (the one with the widest labels) and place it relative to the second plot's axis at `10%` above.  This has the advantages of (a) using the standard labelling style and (b) positioning that will vary in a sensible way with different plot sizes.  The main choice being made is which plot to attach it to, the choice being based on that with the widest labels.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units,groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=ylabel,y unit=m/s,
      every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel cs:1.1)}]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1000) (2,0)};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used your approach, it certainly feels less hackish than mine. :)