# Pgfplots: Adding text to group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I have group plot which consists of 2 rows and 3 columns. I need to add text to left of the figure and below of of the figure, very similar to this :
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{external} % set up externalization
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % activate     externalisation
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape     -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"&&
pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=2,connect spies}]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    vertical sep=0,
    group name=my plots,
    group size=3 by 2,    },
 ybar,
width=8cm,
height=6cm,
ymin=0, 
xtick align=inside,
]
\nextgroupplot[ymax = 80,xmin = -2, xmax=10,xticklabel pos = right]

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 60,xmin = -2, xmax=4,xticklabel pos = right]

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 60 ,ymin = 0.1,xmin = -5, xmax=5,xticklabel pos = right,ytick = {20,40,60},xtick = {-4,-2,0,2,4}]

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 60,xmin = -5, xmax=5]

\nextgroupplot[ymax = 40,xmin = -1, xmax=1]

\nextgroupplot[xmin=-6,xmax=2,ymax = 70]

\end{groupplot} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you to add the labels.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: `ylabel` for the first groupplot and `xlabel` for the second?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have six plots, 2x3, while I can do the first xlabel as you have said, I can't do that for xlabel.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you add an `xlabel` to the bottom, center groupplot? Can you show us the code for your figure? (We don't need the data I'd guess, so you can remove the `\addplot` lines.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry you are right. I can't do that for ylabel. I will add code in a minute.

Comment: So what you really want is to have just one `ylabel` centered vertically between the two rows of plots? [Common label for a groupplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131446) or even [Create x and y label which overlaps for multiple plots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117759)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think first link you have given will work. Do you have any idea why this question is downvoted ?

Comment: Probably because it was very hard to understand exactly what you wanted, and there was no code example. It's still not really clear from text in the question that you want just one ylabel centered vertically on the two rows. Perhaps I should have been able to understand it, but I clearly wasn't.  Unrelated note: Don't load `epsfig`, `graphicx` handles all the things you need for including images.