# Pgfplots for every group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, groupplots

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75444/align-ylabels-of-grouped-plots-at-a-common-line) I want to align my y labels of groupplots.
The style

```
ylabel absolute, y label/.append style={yshift=0em},
```

does the trick, and thus I want to apply this to every group plot.
However, I don't really understand the settings category thing that's going on in tikz/pgfplots. I've tried many variations of the code below, which all compiled fine, but had no effect. Could someone point out how I can adress each group plot and append the above line to the style? *And maybe point out how to do this in general (where to find the subcategories etc)?

Basically, what I try to achieve is a way to modify the style of each group (groupplot?) and append the above ylabel absolute positioning. So something like `every axis/ylabel`, but for groups. (The former doesn't work, since it misplaces the ylabel of 3D plots.)

Minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots} % needs to be loaded exactly like this
\pgfplotsset{ /pgfplots/group/.append style = {
    ylabel absolute, y label/.append style={yshift=0em},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
     group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left
    },height=4cm, width=4cm]
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={foo},]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (-0.1,-0.1) (-0.2,-0.2)};
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={bar},]
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be really nice if you added a complete example as well, so that we don't have to set up everything ourselves to test.

Comment: When adding a `\documentclass` and `document` environment your code produced aligned ylabels regardless of whether those styles are included or not. Do you have a `compat` setting in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the `groupplots` library, I see that the style `/pgfplots/group/every plot` is added to each `\nextgroupplot`. So to only affect axes in `groupplots` environments, append to that style, e.g.

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/group/every plot/.append style = {
    ylabel absolute, y label/.append style={yshift=0em},
  }
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/group/every plot/.append style = {
    ylabel absolute, y label/.append style={yshift=0em},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
     group name=my plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left
    },height=4cm, width=4cm]
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={foo}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (-0.1,-0.1) (-0.2,-0.2)};
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={bar}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=abc]
\addplot3 coordinates {(0,0,0)(1,1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would but sadly this affects the second axes of all 3D plots aswell (they are in some axes too^^). So the y-label for those jumps arround to the place, where the x label should be. I'll refine my statement of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @mike Was that better?

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. Could you enlighten me, where/how you found out, that it's 'pgfplots/group/every plot/'?

Comment: @mike Well, I took the complicated route, and looked at the code of the `groupplots` library, and tried to find where a new axis was added to the group. But I see that it is mentioned in the manual as well, where it says that it is equivalent to adding options to the `groupplot` environment.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm really satisfied. However, the directory scheme is really strange: as you showed me you need group/every plot/.append style for the general settings of every group, but just e.g. group/vertical sep=2cm to change the group specific options. Anyway, thanks again!